# Are there products that have not been ordered in the past three months as measured from Fiscal Year End?

Tags: sql

I got this table: http://www.dofactory.com/sql/sandbox and I need to find the products that have not been ordered in the past three month. 
I got this so far, and I have no idea how I actually display those products that wasn't ordered. Need some help here! Thank you!

```
SELECT  ProductName
FROM Product
INNER JOIN OrderItem ON Product.Id=OrderItem.ProductId
INNER JOIN [Order] ON [Order].Id=OrderItem.OrderId
WHERE OrderDate BETWEEN '2014/01/30' AND '2014/04/30' 
GROUP BY ProductName
```

Answer (score 1):

Such a query suggests `not exists`.  However, a `left join` also works:

```
SELECT p.ProductName
FROM Product p LEFT JOIN
     OrderItem oi
     ON p.Id = oi.ProductId LEFT JOIN
     [Order] o
     ON o.Id = oi.OrderId AND
        o.OrderDate BETWEEN '2014-01-30' AND '2014-04-30' 
WHERE o.Id IS NULL
```